# django: dynamically inserting comment form using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm building a Q&A site where one can comment on questions and their answers.Its a threaded commenting system with ajax.

**this is the javascript part:**

```
function bindPostCommentHandler()
{
    $('.commentFormWrapper form').submit(function() {
    var current = $(this); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: current.serialize(),
            url: "{% comment_form_target %}",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                $('.submit', current).html('<img id="preloader" class="va-mid" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}img/indicator.gif" title="processing.." />');
                $('#commentError').remove();
            },
            success: function(html, textStatus) {   
                current.parent().replaceWith(html);
                bindPostCommentHandler();                
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               $('#commentError').remove();
                $('.submit', current).html('<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-post small-button" value="Submit" />');
                if(xhr.status == 400){
                    current.before('<li id="commentError" class="no-bullet errornote margin10">OOPS ! your comment looked liked a spam. Try again with some modifications.</li>');
                }else {
                    current.before('<li id="commentError" class="no-bullet errornote margin10">Your comment was unable to be posted at this time. You may try after sometime.</li>');
                }   

            //bindPostCommentHandler();             

            }
        });
        return false;
    });        
}
$(document).ready(function() {
 bindPostCommentHandler();
});
```

**the html part:**

```
<!-- comment form for question -->
<div class="commentFormWrapper">                
     {% render_comment_form for question %}
</div>

<!-- comment form for answers -->
{% for answer in question.answers.all %}
<div class="commentFormWrapper">                
     {% render_comment_form for answer %}
</div>
```

**The problem is**, when there is only a single form in a page it works smoothly. With multiple forms its working but sending the request to the server muliple times(grows in multiples).

Also, it would be better to dynamically insert/remove forms. But if I add the html for forms manually, I'll miss out csrf tokens and timestamp fields in the comment form. Anybody has solutions to these ?

Comment: When do you call your bindPostCommentHandler function? Is it perhaps called multiple times?

Comment: I call it once at the page loading time and once when the comment was posted successfully. You ca see that inside $.ajax({...success:function(..){ --here-- }.

Is the problem occurring due to html tags class name . Should I use id's instead and then bind.

Comment: style="tdisplay:none;", should that be style="display:none;"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, when the `success` function is called, then you call `bindPostCommentHandler` (again), which binds the anonymous function **again** to all form objects. I.e. after one submission, every form has two functions bound to the submit event, after two submission, three and so on.

So you have to change the `success` part of the Ajax function to only add the handler to the form contained in the response.

Maybe like this (I don't know if this works, I am not that good in Javascript/jQuery):

**Edit:**

You mentioned the first one is working. Then the code is probably not working because, the DOM gets replaced. See my updated code (use `html`instead of `replace`).

**Edit 2:**

What about changing your HTML structure. Just wrap another `div` around the comments and the form and replace the contents of this. This should definitely work. Something like

```
<div class="new_around_comments">
   <div class="comments"></div>
   <div class="commentFormWrapper">
       <!-- Form -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Then you have to call two times `parent()`:

```
function bindPostCommentHandler(parent)
{
    parent.find('form').submit(function() {
    var current = $(this); 
        $.ajax({
            //...
            success: function(html, textStatus) {
                // Edit 2
                parent = current.parent().parent()
                parent.html(html);
                bindPostCommentHandler(parent);         
            },
            //...
        });
        return false;
    });        
}
$(document).ready(function() {
 var parent = $('.commentFormWrapper')
 bindPostCommentHandler(parent);
});
```

Comment: the error u mentioned is the one I'm facing. But your solution does not work

Comment: No error, but the browser redirects to the form preview page instead of retrieving it through ajax. It could be the case if it is not being binded but your solution seems to bind it!!!

Comment: Ah I think I got it. `children` only looks for child elements not for descendant elements (I always forget this). Change `children` to `find` if the `form` tag is not a direct child of `.commentFormWrapper`.

Comment: What exactly is not working, the first submit or submits after the first submit (i.e. after the success function is executed once?)

Comment: there is only one child of .commentFormWrapper and it is <form></form>. So using children should work.Anyway using find also does not help.
If I see what's in current.parent() using alert(current.parent.html()); It shows the form, but cannot bind. What's wrong?

Comment: using html on parent will create nested .commentFormWrapper.
Also, I  think the dom is replaced with a new one with current.parent().replaceWith(html); , so why this is not binded.

<strong>Ho do u highlight text in comments</strong>

Comment: The same way as in **questions** (`**questions**`). Why not just return the response without a `.commentFormWrapper`?

Comment: because the response may not always return a **.commentFormWrapper**.
When the comment is posted successfully first the **posted comment** and then **.commentFormWrapper** is *displayed*

Comment: Do you have to return a new form in the response? Or would it be sufficient just to return the comment(s) ?

Comment: thanx for u'r help! You solved my problem.And **u r good** at jquery.

Comment: Anand can I see a live example of this jquery comment form. I am trying to implement a jquery form but I only have the html part handle it has been kind of difficult for me to star with the jquery.

Answer (score 1):

assign an #id to every form, and use this id instead of 'this'

```
var current_id = $(this).attr("id");
```

Comment: then I need to add an argument to bindPostCommentHandler. Have u implemented something like this?